# Unknown column 'actions_in_group' in 'field list'

Tags: mysql, select, group-by

I keep getting: **Unknown column 'actions_in_group' in 'field list'**

Here's the SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4ddf0/19

```
SELECT *, 
   SUM(actions_in_group) AS total_rows_in_group,
   GROUP_CONCAT(in_collection) AS complete_collection
   FROM (SELECT stream.*,
          COUNT(stream.id) AS actions_in_user_group,
          GROUP_CONCAT(stream.id) AS actions_in_user_collection
       FROM stream
       INNER JOIN follows
       ON stream.user_id = follows.following_user
       WHERE follows.user_id = '0'
       GROUP BY stream.user_id,
            date(stream.stream_date)
     ) As something 
   GROUP BY object_id,
            date(stream.stream_date)
   ORDER BY stream.stream_date DESC;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SUM` should be on `actions_in_user_group`, not `actions_in_group`

Same goes with `actions_in_user_collection`

I also added `groupby_stream_date` to assist with the `group by`

```
SELECT *, 
   SUM(actions_in_user_group) AS total_rows_in_group,
   GROUP_CONCAT(actions_in_user_collection) AS complete_collection
   FROM (SELECT stream.*,date(stream.stream_date) groupby_stream_date,
          COUNT(stream.id) AS actions_in_user_group,
          GROUP_CONCAT(stream.id) AS actions_in_user_collection
       FROM stream
       INNER JOIN follows
       ON stream.user_id = follows.following_user
       WHERE follows.user_id = '0'
       GROUP BY stream.user_id,
            date(stream.stream_date)
     ) As something 
   GROUP BY object_id,
            groupby_stream_date
   ORDER BY groupby_stream_date DESC;
```

Comment: Using `SELECT *` on a `GROUP BY` query is patently wrong.

Comment: @ypercube but perfectly acceptable in the MySQL parallel universe :-) (BTW it worked in the sqlfiddle (which is a subuniverse))

Comment: "Acceptable" as in working but still wrong. "Wrong" meaning it will produce meaningless results.

Comment: @ypercube explain please.